# Tag [mipsel] vs [mips] - should [mipsel] be a synonym?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I noticed there are over 1500 results returned for tag [mips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mips) and all of 8 returned for [mipsel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mipsel).

Externally (e.g. Linux kernel or buildroot) `mipsel` is often used to refer to a little processor system or cross compiler,etc. specifically. LE vs BE are often used to differentiate in documentation if there is a need to discuss both.

Tag [mips] seems to be used in SO to refer to both architectures; I suspect in many cases the poster (whwther Q or A) seems to know or care. Given the lack of a symmetric tag for BE, especially when apart from being mips the endianness makes no difference to the question, should [mipsel] be retired, or made a synonym with appropriate tag wiki reference? Otherwise 1500+ posts need to be check for which tag to apply if there was to be a mips-be tag of some kind created for symmetry?

Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: There are also existing [little-endian] and [big-endian] and [endianness] tags if this is relevant to the question. Perhaps I can note that in the tag wiki

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a kind of foolish to have both tags. mipsel vs mips is used for build environments, not questions...